# Package tabularx breaks document class svproc

Tags: tabularx, keywords

I am using the document class svproc, as I am writting a paper for a conference that requires it.

```
\documentclass{svproc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

Everything is normal, until I use the `\keywords` command, inside the abstract:

```
\begin{abstract}
\keywords{keyword1 \and keyword2}
\end{abstract}
```

The error I get is:

```
\endarray ->\crcr 
              \egroup \egroup \@arrayright \gdef \@preamble {}
l.94 ...ive annotation \and web-based annotation.}
```

Looking at the document class `svproc.cls`, I see that such a command is defined:

```
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\addvspace\baselineskip
\noindent\keywordname\enspace\ignorespaces#1}%
\@ifundefined{printindex}{}{\def\printautindex{\let\indexname=\autindexname
\addtocmark[2]{\indexname}\@input@{\jobname.ind}}}%
}
```

I assume that the tabularx package somehow changes this command. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: don't show only snippets. Provide a small but complete example *and* a link to the class.

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue. Using `author.tex` and `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.10) 
svproc.cls    2016/07/20 v1.3 
tabularx.sty    2020/01/15 v2.11c `

Comment: Have you tried adding the \and in the keywords?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `\and` commands from inside the `\keywords` command, seems to fix the problem:

```
\begin{abstract}
\keywords{keyword1, keyword2}
\end{abstract}
```

Using a simple comma (against the example latex file for the document class) works.